# Is Wild Magic a Prerequisite for a Chaos Sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-4e, sorcerer, wild-magic

Is Wild Magic a prerequisite to playing a Chaos Sorcerer? If yes, when *Wild Soul* is used, how does the outcome affect the powers that already have a damage type?
**Explanation :** If I roll a 5 (Lightning), how will Burning Spray [At-Will ✦ Arcane, Fire, Implement] be affected?

> **Wild Soul :** When you finish an extended rest, roll a d10 to determine a damage type.
>
> | d10 | Damage Types |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Acid |
> | 2 | Cold |
> | 3 | Fire |
> | 4 | Force |
> | 5 | Lightning |
> | 6 | Necrotic |
> | 7 | Poison |
> | 8 | Psychic |
> | 9 | Radiant |
> | 10 | Thunder |
>
> You gain resist 5 to that damage type until the end of your next
> extended rest. The resistance increases to 10 at 11th level and 15 at
> 21st level. While you have resistance to that damage type, your arcane
> powers ignore any target’s resistance to that damage type up to the
> value of your resistance.

Also is it possible to play a Chaos Sorcerer using Dragon Magic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Any character can be a "Chaos Sorcerer"

From PHB2, p138:

> **Chaos Sorcerer**
> ...
> **Suggested Class Feature:** Wild Magic
> **Suggested Feat:** Arcane Spellfury
> **Suggested Skills:** Arcana, Bluff, Endurance, Insight
> **Suggested At-Will Powers:** *chaos bolt*, *storm walk*
> **Suggested Encounter Power:** *bedeviling burst*
> **Suggested Daily Power:** *dazzling ray*

Notice that all of those start with "suggested"? There is *no such thing* as a "Chaos Sorcerer" in 4e; it's not a mechanical term, it's just the name for a build that the designers thought was conceptually cohesive.

Remember that 4e explicitly allows players to reflavor their powers. As long as you don't change what the power *does*, you can **describe** it however you want. You can absolutely take Dragon Magic and make a "chaos sorcerer" by simply describing your spells as chaos energy (they'll still do whatever damage type they say they do, but they can *look* like whatever you want).

As for Wild Soul + Burning Spray, if you roll lightning for your Wild Soul and then use Burning Spray, your Burning Spray will ignore 5/tier *lightning* resistance on your targets. Which probably won't help much unless you've made it deal lightning damage (using a Lightning dagger or the Arcane Admixture feat, for example; *not* by reflavoring it, since that can't change damage types).